# is it stable to running tomcat, apache as reverse proxy, mysql on the same server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, tomcat

im running dedicated ubuntu server from hoster, has enough cores (12) and good amount memmory 64 GB (ECC). Im actually running tomcat and mysql service in a prodcution environment , but i still want also reverse proxy for my tomcat. Is it recommended or stable to use all the 3 service on the same server  ? Can i get later trouble or issue for for my intentions ?

i'm thankfull for any help

blackbeard

Comment: Depends on your workload, but in general it's OK to run them on the same machine, when using correct and safe configurations, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on load on the system and the configuration (in case DB would use 64GB RAM the most probably it may be sometime the issue on lack of resources ;-) ).

In case you know the resource requirements it may be coexisting on the same system without any issue. Tomcat and reverse proxy will be ok for sure. The part to check I would see in DB (depends how and how much it is used).

Comment: ty, you say it should monitoring the db, if they db using 64 GB memmory

Comment: It was the worst use case of config... you can configure db for memory limit. The meaning is that db should be configured to leave some memory for other processes ;). I think "normal" db do not need more then 24 -32 GB of memory.

Comment: great thx for you advice :)

Comment: Tune things, especially MySQL, to use as much RAM as practical _without swapping_.